# Remove unfinished polygons/polylines in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So my problem is: I'm trying to find a way to clear a drawn polygon while it is still being drawn. Even when I create a new `google.maps.Map` object I still can't get rid of the old polygon or polyline such as doing this:

[image: Cursor outside map]

Currently, I store all drawn polygons/polylines in an array and delete them when needed by calling the array element. The only problem is I can't delete a polygon/polyline unless it is in the array. Here's the relevant code:

```js
//Code to reset map
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(latSE, lonNW),
    new google.maps.LatLng(latNW, lonSE));

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng((latNW + latSE) / 2,
        (lonNW + lonSE) / 2),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
drawingManager.setMap(map);
deleteAllRegions(); //remove all regions after switching
```

And the delete regions function:

```js
//delete all completed polygons
function deleteAllRegions() {
    for (var j = 0; j < regions.length; j++) {
        regions[j].setMap(null)
    }
    regions = new Array();
    for (var j = 0; j < paths.length; j++) {
        paths[j].setMap(null)
    }
    paths = new Array();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's less difficult,

1. call `drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);`

   This will finish the current action, e.g. when you currently draw a polygon the polygon will be completed and the `overlay_complete`-event fires (which should push the shape into the array)
2. run the code that clears the shapes(the last shape will also be inside the array)

No need to re-create map or drawingManager

Answer (score 0):

Just found out I wasn't deleting the `drawingManager` when clearing. The new code is:

```js
//Code to reset map
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(latSE, lonNW),
    new google.maps.LatLng(latNW, lonSE));

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng((latNW + latSE) / 2,
        (lonNW + lonSE) / 2),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
};
//create new drawing manager
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControlOptions: {
        drawingModes: [
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
        ]
    },
    polylineOptions:{
        editable: true
    },
    polygonOptions:{
        editable: true
    }
});
//create new map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
drawingManager.setMap(map);
deleteAllRegions(); //remove all regions after switching
```

It seems since the drawing manager was the same, it would keep the previously drawn polygons.